# The bounty optional message box is misleading

Tags: feature-request, bounty

When setting a bounty, I have the option to set an extended explanation of what I require. The input box allows me to input newlines and blank lines, which leads me to think that the full question/answer markdown syntax (lists, paragraphs) should be available; however, [actually only the comment subset](https://superuser.com/questions/601469/getting-chapters-to-start-on-a-new-page-in-a-pandoc-generated-pdf) of the syntax is available.

This shouldn't behave like the comments, where pressing enter submits it, as this is the final stage of Bounty submission and that is a more permanent thing than disposable comments. As far as I can see, one of these behaviours should be the case:

- `Enter` should be disabled entirely for the bounty submission
- There should be a live preview of the bounty submission, as for questions and answers